# Function Not getting called

Tags: python, pygame

I have function which checks the score and will(I haven't finished) increases level if the score hits the given score, my function:

```
def levels(Score):
 if score >= 100:
   enemies = 6
   velocity = 2
```

and I'm calling it in the game loop:

```
levels(score)
```

The function never gets executed, my source code http://pastebin.com/JPZSTA6a 
Line: 35-38 and 150

Thank you

Comment: What is your evidence for the claim that "the function never gets executed"?

Comment: Have you tried putting a `print` statement in the function to test whether or not it is called?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel because if the function is executed it will throw up an error message.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't put functions inside a function unless it requires to be in. They can be put outside. It makes you code easier to debug. And you wrote `score` instead of `Score`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is being called, but you are assigning to `enemies` and `velocity` in the function, so they are local to the function, and are then discarded when the function returns.  So your function is called, but has no lasting effect.

You need to read about locals and globals in Python.  As others point out you also have both `Score` and `score` here.  Python is case-sensitive, those are different names.

Answer (score 2):

You have `if score >= 100` when you probably meant `if Score >= 100`. The function gets executed, it's just that the if statement always evaluates to false.

Comment: that was one of the errors, but still not working. the if statement if placed in the game loop does execute.

Answer (score 1):

It's a scoping issue, the variables you're referring (enemies and velocity) to are created further down inside a while loop so they're not in scope in the function where you're trying to modify them.  You need to read up on [Execution model](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html) it should be able to clarify scoping rules.

Comment: I tried placing score,enemies and velocity in the game() but still the func does not get called

Answer (score 0):

Your code, paraphrased:

```
def game():

    def levels(Score):
        print 'levels!'

    while start == True:
        print 'start is indeed True!'
        while not finish or falling: 
            'I am not Finnish'     
            for i in range(enemies):
                'alas for I am beset by enemies!'
                levels(score)
```

So, why isn't levels() being called? I suppose one of those many control flow items doesn't go the way you want. I can't say for example whether or not your enemies variable is empty but I can tell you that print is your friend.