# Function inside class not being called

Tags: python, function

I have a python class and couple of functions, 1st calling 2nd. However, 2nd is never getting called. Also the line after `_method2()` invocation is never executed.

```
class call_methods():
    def _method1(self, context):
            print "Now call method 2";  
            this._method2(context);
            print "Finish"; 
            return {}

    def _method2(self, context={}):
            print "method 2 called"
            return {}
```

Output:

```
Now call method 2
```

Only 1st print statement comes out.

The question is similar to [Function Not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359507/function-not-getting-called) but solution suggested there doesn't seem to apply to this.

Comment: `self` <--> `this`? and where is the `self` as first argument of `_method2`?

Comment: That code should give you an error. What can you learn from the error message?

Comment: `this._method2(context)` should be `self.`, as your self is the name of the instance, and not this like in Javascript. Also, you don't need to end lines with semi-colons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this._method2(context); ===>  self._method2(context)
```

`this` does not exist in python.You have to use `self`.Also `;` is not needed.Instead follow proper indentation.Modify your second function as

```
def _method2(self, context={}):
```

Comment: The signature for `_method2` lacks `self`. The code (as it is now) will work, but this is another thing to be aware of.

Comment: It's a problem of juggling between different languages. So, I ended using `this` instead of `self`. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You have the name `this` which ***is not defined***, so Python will complain. You can alter your second `method` `_method2()`  to take the argument `self` which, in Python, is a convention signifying the `instance` of a class you have created and want to reference:

```
class call_methods:
     def _method1(self, context):
         print "Now call Method 2"
         self._method2(context)
         print "finish"
         return {}

     def _method2(self, context={}):
         print "Method 2 Called"
         return {}
```

If you want to call `_method2` via `_method1` using the ***instance*** of a ***class*** you have created, you must again provide the `self` argument in the call to `_methdo2()` that references the instance, this is done ***implicitly*** by calling the function on the `self` argument of `_method1`.

Your output after altering will be:

```
In [27]: cls1 = call_methods()

In [28]: cls1._method1("con")
Now call Method 2
Method 2 Called
finish
Out[28]: {}
```

<sub>P.S: No need for parentheses `()` when declaring a class, it makes no difference. You might want to take a look at [New Style Classes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass) in Python 2</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The problem was using `this` instead of `self`. However, python never threw a error/exception/warning for using a non-existing variable/object. It just stopped executing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
    class call_methods():


    def _method1(self,context):

        print "Now call method 2";  

        this._method2(context);

        print "Finish"; 

        return {}


    def _method2(self, context={}):

        print "method 2 called"


        return {}
```